# Do I have to check with Lyle to get Happy Room Academy rewards?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In New Leaf you get your HRA score by talking to Lyle instead of in the mail. Thus far I haven't gotten any rewards, so I'm wondering: Do I have to check with Lyle when I hit a thresh hold to get a reward, or will I get it by mail automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you do not have to talk to Lyle to receive your rewards. I hit the 10,000 point benchmark in the game last week, and when I checked my mail (which I do immediately upon loading the game if I have any), I had a letter from the HHA with the 10k tier reward attached to it. So it'll automatically be sent out without needing to check in with him.